# Submit button for input versus textarea for js html

Tags: javascript, html, meteor

2 questions:

1. Submit works when I hit "enter" on keyboard. However, submit button itself isnt working.
2. If I wish to change the entire `<form>` to a `<textarea>` form, how should I tweak the code? I tried to change the event but the form doesnt fire.

**The event js**

```
  'submit form': function(e, template) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $body = $(e.target).find('[name=body]');

    var comment = {
      body: $body.val(),
      postId: template.data._id
    };

    var errors = {};
    if (! comment.body) {
      errors.body = "Input and/or attach content?";
      return Session.set('commentSubmitErrors', errors);
    }

    Meteor.call('commentInsert', comment, function(error, commentId) {
      if (error){
        throwError(error.reason);
      } else {
        $body.val('');
      }
    });
```

**The html**

```
    <div class="page-content message-content">
        <form class="form-send-message" data-keyboard-attach >
        <!-- <form> -->
            <input name="body" id="body" type="text" placeholder="content">
            <a href="#" class="button" type="submit">comment</a> 

        <!-- <a href="#" class="link" type="submit">
               <i class="icon ion-android-send"></i> 
               picture icon doesnt work
             </a> -->

        <!-- what I aim to have

         <textarea placeholder="add comment" name="body" id="body"></textarea>
        <a href="#" class="link" type="submit">
            <i class="icon ion-android-send"></i> --> 

        </form>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

an `<a>` tag does not have a type attribute - you could make it an `<input type="submit">` and style it how you like or else put a click listener on the `<a>` tag, but best practice would be the former